# Cannot open localhost with XAMPP

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

Everything was fine until I changed the password of the username "root". Then after doing some research online, I found the config.inc.php file and found the code "$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';" which was in "// quotes". The question is this: I got rid of the hashtags to make it a valid code and not a comment but it will not let me save the file. I know this is due to authorization error but how can I process with it?

I do apologize in advance if this was asked already. I wasn't able to find the right solution to my problem.

Comment: what is the error that u getting? describe moreeeeeee

Comment: Well the first error says "#2002 - no such file or directory - the server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured.)"